# Código HTML no funciona en Readme.md

Tags: html, github, markdown

estoy haciendo la documentación de un proyecto y he leído que se puede utilizar código HTML en el fichero readme.md de github. El problema viene cuando he subido el código a github y es que, en la previsualización en local si que funciona y mantiene el formato que quiero (imágen con los textos a la derecha de la imágen) pero en github me lo cambia y lo pone todo como quiere. Os adjunto imágenes y el código para ver si sabéis como puedo hacer para solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias a todos!!

[image: En Github]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
## Encabezado de Prueba
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <img width=80px; height=80px src="https://aprendomates.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/simpsons.jpg"/>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; margin-left: 10px; margin-top:-20px;">
            <p>Texto 1</p>
            <p style="margin-top:-20px;">Texto 2</p>
            <p style="margin-top:-20px;">Texto 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:flex;">
        <img width=80px; height=80px src="https://aprendomates.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/simpsons.jpg"/>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: column; margin-left: 10px; margin-top:-20px;">
            <p>Texto 1</p>
            <p style="margin-top:-20px;">Texto 2</p>
            <p style="margin-top:-20px;">Texto 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Diría que esta pregunta está fuera de tema en StackOverflow, y sería una excelente pregunta para el soporte de github. Dado que el dialecto de markdown de github está razonablemente bien documentado, quizás puedas encontrar una explicación/solución leyendo la documentación, por ejemplo, de los [bloques HTML](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-blocks).  Mi sospecha es que tienen su propia hoja de estilo y que no todo lo que está en las etiquetas `<style>` está soportado. Como sea, creo que la idea de adoptar y utilziar MarkDown es, justamente, no escribir HTML y mantener las cosas más simples.

Comment: Igual, dado que tu puedes ver el resultado de tu markdown en el navegador, sugiero que inspecciones qué es lo que está generando y de allí puedes hacerte una idea. Si eres más curioso y dado que me quedé interesado en el tema, una búsqueda rápida me arrojó [este hilo](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/245) en el _tracker_ de gh, que luego me llevó a [este código](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb), que es la parte medular del _sanitizador_ de HTML del parser: